# Auto focus Input within React Native Viewpager

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-viewpager, react-navigation, react-native-elements

I'm using a React Native Viewpager to take in user entry, and move to the next page **on button press**. Important to note that moving to the next page happens on button press, and not by normal scrolling, which is disabled.

The best way I could think to handle this was to have a state on the ViewPager, which would propagate into the child Entries.

ViewPager.tsx:

```
export default function ViewPager({ route, navigation }) {

    const ref: React.RefObject<ViewPager> = React.createRef();
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);

    let setEntryPage = (page: number) => {
        ref.current?.setPage(page);
        setCurrentPage(page);
    }


    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <ViewPager
                style={styles.viewPager}
                initialPage={0}
                ref={ref}
                scrollEnabled={false}
            >
                {
                    GlobalStuff.map((entry, index) => {
                        return (
                            <Entry
                                key={index}
                                index={index}
                                pagerFocusIndex={currentPage}
                                pagerLength={quizDeck?.litems.length!}
                                setEntryPage={setEntryPage}
                            />
                        )
                    })
                }
            </ViewPager>
        </View>
    );
};
```

Entry.tsx:

```
export function Entry(props: EntryProps) {

    const inputRef: React.RefObject<Input> = React.createRef();
    if (props.pagerFocusIndex === props.index) {
        inputRef.current?.focus();
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <Input
                // ...
                ref={inputRef}
            />
            <IconButton
                icon="arrow-right-thick"
                color={colorTheme.green}
                onPress={() => {
                    props.index !== props.pagerLength - 1 ?
                        props.setEntryPage(props.index + 1) :
                        props.navigation!.reset({ index: 0, routes: [{ name: recapScreenName as any }] });
                }}
            />
// ...
```

Unfortunately, `inputRef` appears to be `null`, and there is probably a better way of achieving what I'm trying to achieve anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything in your render loop will be called every time the component renders.

```
    // This is called on every render
    const inputRef: React.RefObject<Input> = React.createRef();
    
    // So is this, it's always null
    if (props.pagerFocusIndex === props.index) {
        inputRef.current?.focus();
    }
```

Put side effects in effects.

```
    // Untested
    const inputRef = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.pagerFocusIndex === props.index) {
            inputRef.current?.focus();
        }
    }, [inputRef.current, props.pagerFocusIndex, props.index]);
```